# JPA2 CriteriaQuery is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables `A` and `B`, `A` has B's foreign key, with the old `Criteria` API everything works fine however with the `CriteriaQuery` API I'm getting an error. What different is happening behind the scenes? To me it's logical that these two pieces of code should do the same thing.

Error

```
Column 'A.PK' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

This works:

```java
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("b"));
return criteria.list();
```

this doesn't:

```java
Session session = getSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get("b"));
return session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
class A {

   @ManyToOne
   private B b;
}

@Entity
class B {

  @Id
  private Long id;
}
```

1. Outdated `Criteria`:

```java
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("b"));
List<B> result = criteria.list();
```

actually execute the query like below:

```sql
select b_id
from A
group by b_id
```

and then fetch B's one by one by executing query like this:

```sql
select * from B where id = ?
```

2. When you use `CriteriaBuilder` hibernate actually tries to fetch data by one query. To fix the query you can do something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<B> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(B.class);
Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
      
Join<A, B> bJoin = root.join("b");
      
criteriaQuery.groupBy(bJoin.get("id"));
criteriaQuery.select( root.get("b") );
List<B> result = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).list();
```